# How to compile QtDesigner user interface (.ui) and resource (.qrc) files with QGIS 3 on Windows?

Tags: pyqgis, qt-designer, qgis-3

I tried to transpose the QGIS 2 process with no success.

I first had to edit C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\etc\ini\python-core.bat which contains references to Python27 instead of Python36.

I run C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\bin\o4w_env.bat to properly configure QGIS python environment, but then, when I launch :

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\apps\Python36\Scripts\pyuic5.bat" -o dockwidget_base.py dockwidget_base.ui
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: Specified module could not be found.
```

Similarly, when I launch :

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99\apps\Python36\Scripts\pyrcc5.bat" -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.99\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyrcc_main.py", line 21, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR, QDir, QFile
ImportError: DLL load failed: Specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need set PyQT5 environments.
This is my scripts for compile QGIS 3 Plugins and have 3 complementary bats.

**compile_ui.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64

set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\bin;%PATH%

cd /d %~dp0

@ECHO ON
::Ui Compilation
call pyuic5 dialog.ui -o gui\generated\ui_dialog.py          

::Resources
call pyrcc5 ui\resources.qrc -o gui\generated\resources_rc.py

@ECHO OFF
GOTO END

:ERROR
   echo "Failed!"
   set ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
   pause

:END
@ECHO ON
```

You only need change `set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64` for `set OSGEO4W_ROOT="C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.99"`, or something like that,

Try using this .bat

*Note: this bat is in the same folder as the plugin*

*Note 2 :* For import import resources_rc need this trick

```
call pyuic5 --import-from <package-name>.gui.generated dialog.ui -o gui\generated\ui_dialog.py`
```

this path probably change in other plugin. [pyuic5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

@sigeal soluton for Note 2 :

```
call pyuic5 dockwidget_base.ui --from-imports -o dockwidget_base.py
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Great answer, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: One question though : "import resources_rc" at the end of generated file gives me a "No module named 'resources_rc'" error. I can get rid of this error with "from . import resources_rc" but this is not a correct solution as the file is generated... Do I miss something ?

Comment: Ok you need add this `call pyuic5 --import-from <package-name>.gui.generated`. Need put the path for your resource file and compile again.

Comment: I ended with this command `call pyuic5 dockwidget_base.ui --from-imports -o dockwidget_base.py`. It works perfectly.

Comment: Update my answer with your solution

Comment: Still not sure what the correct line is for the Resources as one example uses pyrcc5 and one uses pyuic5. Could you give a complete example line? Also, for those who are using QT Designer to create a standalone GUI outside of QGIS, note that you don't need the Resources call.

Comment: for resources is pyrcc5 and pyuic5 is for compile the .ui

Comment: Would this be correct? call pyrcc5 <path to>resources.qcc --from-imports -o dockwidget_base.py

Answer (score 2):

After having found out everything about the environment variables and knowing what I was searching for, I found the file **/osgeo4w_root/bin/python-qgis-dev.bat**

When called from the active osgeo4w shell, it sets all the env. variables by calling the corresponding .bat files (as suggested by Francisco)!