# Using PyPDF2 in PyQGIS 3!

Tags: qgis-3, pdf

I use PdfFileMerger from PyPDF2 in a plugin that I want to migrate from qgis 2 to 3 but it seems that this lib doesn't exist in qgis 3 (python 3.6).

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Install PyPDF2 using pip.

```
python -m pip install PyPDF2
```

Remember that you need set python interpreter for use qgis 3 (python 3.6)
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268606/49538

And fro using it:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
```

[image]