# Importing QGIS 3.10 python module from system Python

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have QGIS 3.10 installed on my Windows 10 system and I want to import the `qgis` module from my system Python installation. I used [this](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/de/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications) description on the QGIS homepage to set my system up. My `PYTHONPATH` variable points to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python`.

Now when importing `qgis`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
```

When adding `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages` to `PYTHONPATH`, importing `qgis` yields this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis   File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore   File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import * ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How do I have to set my `PYTHONPATH` to be able to properly work with QGIS from my system Python installation?

Comment: you need set some environments variables. look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268606/49538

Comment: hmm, thats for a OSGeo4W installation. Are the steps for a standalone QGIS installation the same or similar?

Comment: only need change set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64 with you QGIS installation