# 'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, windows-10

I installed QGIS 3.0 on Windows 10. I get this error everytime i run the pyrcc4 or pyrcc5 command:

> 'pyrcc4' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Even if I find a place with a `pyrcc4.exe` file or a place with `apyrcc5.bat` file and add the path to the environment variables I get the same error.

In the previous installation of osgeo4w i had a pyqtdev folder or something similar appear I think it was on C/. Was there supposed to be such a folder, do I need to download pyqt separately?

Comment: you have a bats and a exe in bin folder,for example `D:\OSGeo4W64\bin`

Comment: I have no pyrcc4 or pyrcc5 bat or exe in the bin folders...

Comment: pyrcc5 are inside `Python36\Scripts` and pyrcc4 in a bin,try reinstall Qgis maybe

Comment: I have a pyrcc5 in: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\Scripts, but even though I add the path to the path & python path variables the command pyrcc5 is not recognized

Comment: @Carmel Han Do you have a QGIS 2.x version also installed in your system? If answer is yes I have a solution.

Comment: @ xunilk I might have, tried to uninstall it, but purhaps there are leftovers, not able to uninstall completly

Comment: check this .bat for run and compile ui using pyrcc5 https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260886/49538

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try running a batch file with the following:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

either place the batch file in your directory with `resources.py` or type in an absolute path.

Comment: It works for me. I had another solution but this is better and quicker. +1.

Comment: The problem is i also have folders missing. for example I am missing the folder of ".qgis2". That's why i think there is a problem with the instalation of Qgis 3.0.0

Comment: do you mean ``C:\users\USERNAME\.qgis2``? In QGIS3.0, this has been moved to ``C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3``

Comment: Works great, but need to adjust the path in the calls to the installed qgis-version. I.e for me today c:\program files\qgis 3.10\bin

Comment: In case anyone is getting the following error - 
`C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyrcc_main.py: File does not exist 'resources.qrc'`

Do a search for 'resources.qrc'.  I found it in the plugin that I had just created with QGIS plugin builder.  Then, make sure to edit the batch file described above to point to the absolute path of resources.qrc.  This solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

For an additional information for people using ubuntu you can install libs like this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

*Kezah's answer applied for OSGeo4W64:*

> Try running a batch file with the following:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"
> call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qt5_env.bat"
> call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat"
>
> @echo on
> pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
> ```
>
> either place the batch file in your directory with `resources.py` or
> type in an absolute path.