# Fixing "The resource compiler pyrcc5 was not found"

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, osgeo4w

I was trying to use Plugin Builder to create custom tool.
When I set up parameters for plugin and press "generate", an error appear.
Same situation in QGIS that was downloaded with OSGEO4W64.

[image]

I looked through some tutorials where it was said that I need to launch OSGeo4W.bat and run pb_tool. But this tool surprisingly not exist in OSGeo4W folder so i tried to test `python3 -m install pb_tool` and got another error:

[image]

Please let me know what can be done here. I simply want to build a button tool with functions I wrote and share it with another colleagues like a python addin in ArcGIS.

Comment: @user2856 I have python 2 installed with ArcGIS, but it is not set as an environment variable. And I typed the exact python 3 from osgeo4w, but it refers to the python 2 which is in the apps folder of osgeo4w. What I have to do?

Comment: @user2856 thanks, that works! However when I want to pack my plugin into a zipfile, after `pb_tool zip` it gives error that `zip or 7z is missing`. Does this tool needs to have something else installed for pb_tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the osgeo4w cmd shell, call [py3_env and qt5_env](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273697/2856) .

You'll also need to install [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org) .

Comment: I installed 7zip but error still exist. Do I have to install it in specific folder?

Comment: No, but you probably need to add the folder that contains 7z.exe to your PATH environment variable. `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\rest of path to 7z folder`

Comment: fine, that works!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, starting from Plugin Builder 3 and QGIS-LTR on MacOS.

Waiting for an official QGIS solution, I've found a simpler trick to solve the problem of pyrcc5, without installing anything more.

1. Edit the plugin_builder.py inside plugin folder, replacing 'pyrcc5' inside cmd instruction with its complete path
2. Save
3. Edit pyrcc5 file, replacing '`dirname $0`/python3.9' with its complete path (or removing quotes)
4. Save
5. Reload Plugin Builder inside QGIS-LTR or open again QGIS-LTR

Everything that deals with 'QGIS-LTR' is ok also for 'QGIS', paths too

Ref: [QGIS' pyrcc5 gives error on macos Catalina](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403560/qgis-pyrcc5-gives-error-on-macos-catalina/456074#456074)