# Plugin not working after building through Plugin Builder in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have been trying to build a plugin through *Plugin Builder 3* and been facing this issue then.

I have been facing the `pyrcc5` issue but I was able to solve it through this link:
[Fixing “The resource compiler pyrcc5 was not found”](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313698/fixing-the-resource-compiler-pyrcc5-was-not-found)

This is the Python error:

```
Couldn't load plugin split_layer' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'split_layer.resources'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA-1/QGIS3~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins [packageName] = package.classFactory (iface)
  File "C:/Users/pabla/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\split_layer\ _init_ .py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .split_layer import Split_Layer
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./pychon\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import (name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/pabla/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\splic_layer\splic_layer.py", line 26, in
    from .resources import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./pychon\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import (name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'split_layer.resources'
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this error?

Comment: Does `resources.py` exist in your plugin folder?

Comment: Yes it is there in the pluginbuilder3 folder but not in the plugin that i have build(i.e split layer folder ) in that there is only resources.qrc

Comment: You have to copy `resources.py` in folder created by pluginbuilder into QGIS plugin folder.

Comment: The problem is solved and please comment down so that i can accept your answer :) :).

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I've re-opened on basis of your comment.  Thank you for replacing the code picture with formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While building a plugin for QGIS using Plugin Builder, if you get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '... .resources'` error after running *Makefile*, you should first check if `resources.py` exists in the folder (source folder) created by Plugin Builder. If it does, copy that file into your plugin folder in QGIS plugin folder (target folder).

If there is no `resources.py` file in the source folder, then, run next code to create `resources.py` from `resources.qrc`.

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

And copy `resources.py` file into target folder or run *Makefile* again.

Note: You can copy all plugin files into target folder manually without running *Makefile*. But still, you will need `resources.py` file. Therefore, you have to generate it via `pyrcc5`.