# QGIS' pyrcc5 gives error on macos Catalina

Tags: qgis, mac, pyqt, pyrcc5

When trying to build a QGIS plugin with Plugin Builder 3, I get the message that `pyrcc5` was not found in my path.

I installed PyQt using `brew install pyqt`, but still nothing. Instead, I tried to run the `pyrcc5` executable that ships with QGIS like this

`/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pyrcc5`

and get this error:

`` ./pyrcc5: line 2: exec: /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/`dirname $0`/python3.8: cannot execute: No such file or directory ``

Am I missing some step in the installation or setup?

macOS Version 10.15.7

QGIS version 3.16.8-Hannover (LTR; installer from the official QGIS website)

Comment: "I tried to run the pyrcc5". How? you type pyrcc5 anywhere, you provide absolute path, you do cd and pyrcc5? Edit you question to add the informations

Comment: pyrcc5 shouldn't be used anymore, in PyQt6 it won't even be available anymore, see e.g. [the qgis dev list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Heads-up-PyQt6-removes-pyrcc-td5446495.html). Was always painful and its purpose is very questionable in a python enviromnent. The plugin builder should remove it too IMO, there's [an issue](https://github.com/g-sherman/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/issues/126) already.

Comment: BTW, the problem is not pyrrc5 here, that exists since it's giving the error. Where's your QGIS python installation actually located? `/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/`dirname $0`/python3.8` probably smth wrong with how pyrcc5 interprets that..

Comment: True, I should rephrase the question. QGIS's python is `/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/`

Comment: yeah, never mind then, `dirname $0` seems to be the culprit or pyrcc5 for not setting the right thing there.

Comment: As mentioned before, you should try to not use pyrcc.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @nnolde for pointing me towards the cause of the brew install not working: `brew install pyqt` installs `pyqt@6`.

`brew install pyqt@5` did the trick.

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

pyqt@5 and in particular its dependency qt@5 has problem with freetype.. It does not the trick for all..

So, waiting for an official QGIS solution, I've found a simpler trick to solve the problem of pyrcc5, without installing anything more.

1. Edit the plugin_builder.py inside plugin folder, replacing 'pyrcc5' inside `cmd` instruction with its complete path (ie. '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pyrcc5'
2. Save
3. Edit pyrcc5 file (located in /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pyrcc5), replacing '`dirname $0`/python3.9' with `dirname $0`/python3.9 (removing quotes)
4. Save
5. Reload Plugin Builder inside QGIS-LTR or open QGIS-LTR again

Everything that deals with 'QGIS-LTR' is ok also for 'QGIS', paths too