# Creating a plugin/button from a Python script and make it usable for others via Zip install or plugin manager

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a Python script I use to edit layers for certain projects. As a processing script from the toolbox and using the Python console, the script works but I can't manage to create a plugin to use it and would like to know how to do that. It has no UI file or anything, it's merely a processing script I would like to make into a button. How can I achieve this? I need it to be reusable for various users.

When I run

```
@echo off
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5.bat -o resources.py resources.qrce
```

I don't get a resources.py to move on further with the guide. I did install pb_tool prior by using `pip install pb_tool` with the OSGeo4W shell.

[Fixing "The resource compiler pyrcc5 was not found"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313698/fixing-the-resource-compiler-pyrcc5-was-not-found) This seems to be the closest thing to my issue but I don't see the solution in it.

Also, upon the plugin creation, I can't manage to get a proper script in my script.py file, it's generic, I'm not sure what I am supposed to put for class names, etc.

edit: As of right now, I, for some reason cannot use some python commands (namely pip) to install pb_tool or any of the otherwise needed operations and I'm not sure where the issue comes from.

Comment: Last letter 'e' in your batch file is a typo? Should be 'qrc', Also be sure, that you are in the right directory, where your plugins is stored.

Comment: @AndreasMüller Thank you for trying to help me. Yes, the extra e is a typo. I managed to run pyrcc5.bat directly from the OSGeo4w shell while being in the plugin directory. As you might have noticed from my other question, I went past that issue with other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile the resource file by running pyrcc5 from the OSGeo4W shell while being in the plugin's directly. For some reason I still ignore, a .bat file with the commands didn't work.