# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have resources.qrc compiled to resources.py using the following batch file:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

I import resources at the beginning of the code but i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'
```

I tried editing the .ui file as explained here:
[QGIS plugin: Problems importing resources (resources_rc) file - plugin doesn't load - PATH problems?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/qgis-plugin-problems-importing-resources-resources-rc-file-plugin-doesnt-l)
But I don't have the exact same lines as mentioned instead of:

```
<resources>
  <include location="resources.qrc"/>
</resources>
```

I have:

```
<resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is the content of the folder:
[image]
Does somebody have a clue what is wrong?

Comment: Post the full code of the .bat file, and a screenshot of the contents of the folder.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto Thank you, added a screenshot, the bat file is in it's full version however

Comment: Try with `from resources import *`

Comment: I'm not answering your question. I personally stopped using resources files in all my plugins. I saw the same in other plugins. Using the filepath on the file system is working well to load icons, images or whatever. We don't have to recompile anymore this file.

Comment: Can you try the bat script from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260743/how-to-compile-qtdesigner-user-interface-ui-and-resource-qrc-files-with-qg That works for me.

Comment: Not for me sadly

Comment: Is that the contents of your resources.qrc file that you posted? If so where did you get it from?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question. Manged to get my plugin to work without importing resources. Was able to compile the resources.qrc file to resources.py the regualar way after running env_3 in the osgeo4w, then things worked out.

Answer (score 3):

As your ParcelCapture.py and resources.py are in same directory you can use relative path like this `from .resources import *` to import resources module into your ParcelCapture.py.
Hope this answers your question.