# Missing pyrcc compiling QGIS item

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, compile

I created a plugin using the QGIS Plugin Builder with QGIS 3.2 and tried to compile it afterwards with the OSGeo4W Shell. In the Shell I navigated to the directory my plugin is installed (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\MYPLUGIN) and typed in the following lines:

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

But I get an error, that pyrcc5 can not be found. But the batchfile is located in the Python 36->Scripts folder in the QGIS 3.2 folder.

I am using Windows 10.

How do I solve or workaround the error?

Comment: did you use the OSGEO4W shell?

Comment: Yes and I also tried with cmd. Same error

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260886/49538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workarround for my problem, even though I did not solve the actual problem:

I installed the OSGeoW64 networkinstallation with qgis desktop and qgis full. Afterwards I installed pip and pb tool using the Windows console. With the pb tool deploy function compiling the plugin worked perfectly, no error messages.